# Delphi connection test with TIdFTP

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-xe4

On my program I'm actually using this code:

```
if IdFTP1.Connect = True then
 begin
  //makes some stuff
 end
else
 begin
  ShowMessage('you got the move like jagger.');
 end;
```

If I am not connected I see an error like

> Socket Error #11001
>
> Host not found

To avoid this, I thought that I could use the code you see above but I am having an error when I use `IdFTP1.Connect = True`.

What could I do?

Comment: Is TIdFtp.Connect a function that returns a boolean?

Comment: The [`Connect`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdFTP_Connect.html) method is currently a procedure, not a function. Which version of Indy are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE4 with the latest indy version

Comment: And please don't tell us that you got an error without quoting the error message

Comment: `Connect()` has NEVER returned a Boolean in any version of Indy. It has ALWAYS raised an exception on error instead.

Comment: And please give useful answers instead of being "wise" @SirRufo

Comment: @RemyLebeau how could I avoid that exception?

Comment: You can't **avoid** it, you need to **catch** it.

Comment: Update your question and post the error message

Comment: I see that @RemyLebeau perfectly answered to my question, so why more useless informations.

Comment: Read http://sscce.org/ and think about other users searching for help (some just search for that error message).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Connect()` does not return a Boolean if it fails. It raises an exception instead:

```
try
  IdFTP1.Connect;
  try
    //makes some stuff
  finally
    IdFTP1.Disconnect;
  end;
except
  ShowMessage('you got the move like jagger.');
end;
```